# ¿Como puedo Rellenar Combo Box en javaFx obteniendo datos desde SQL Server en servidor externo?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, crud

estoy comenzando a realizar mi primer aplicación en Java, y particularmente elegí JAVAFX por medio del entorno NETBEANS.
Estoy desarrollando un CRUD, y hasta ahora logre conectarme a la base de datos, genere un formulario de inicio de sesión pero mi jefe desea que en vez de que haya un TXT AREA, coloque un COMBO BOX, obteniendo asi los usuarios que hay en la BD y luego el usuario puede colocar su contraseña. 
Mas allá de este COMBO BOX, en general debo rellenar varios, y hasta ahora no he logrado entender como hacerlo.
Intente por medio de arraylist, observable list y lo mas probable es que no entienda bien el concepto o bien mi diseño general del CRUD no este estructurado a travez de un patrón.
Luego de resolver este tema debería pasar todo el proyecto a MAVEN e hibernate que tampoco 
Si alguien puede colaborar conmigo en orientarme en donde le estoy pifiendo me haría un gran favor!

**Este es el Cogido de la Conexión**

```
package ar.com.consular.conexiones;
import ar.com.consular.DAO.ConexionesDao.SqlTbUsuariosDao;
import ar.com.consular.DAO.UsuariosDAO;
import ar.com.consular.clases.TbUsuarios;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexionSqlServer {

public static Connection conectar() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://XX:XX:XX:1433;databaseName=XX;username=XX;password=XX;";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionSqlServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return con;

}

public void desconectar(Connection con) {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionSqlServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

**Este es el codigo del Controlador SistemaLogueoController**

```
package controladores;

import ar.com.consular.DAO.ConexionesDao.SqlTbUsuariosDao;
import ar.com.consular.DAO.UsuariosDAO;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class SistemaLogueoController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private PasswordField pwdLogUsuario;
@FXML
private Button btnLogUsuario;
@FXML
private Button btnOlvidarPasssUsuario;
@FXML
private Button btnCerrarUsuario;
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private TextField txtLogUsuario;
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPaneLog;

private Connection con;
private ResultSet rs;
private PreparedStatement ps;
private ObservableList<SqlTbUsuariosDao> listaUsuarios;
@FXML
private ComboBox<SqlTbUsuariosDao> cmbUsuarios;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    con = ar.com.consular.conexiones.ConexionSqlServer.conectar();
    //Aca NO SE COMO CARGAR LA LISTA DEL DAO!
    listaUsuarios = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    cmbUsuarios.setItems(listaUsuarios);




}

/*public class ConvertidorCmbUser extends StringConverter<SqlTbUsuariosDao> {

    @Override
    public String toString(SqlTbUsuariosDao cmbUsuarios) {
        return cmbUsuarios.obtenerTodos();
    }

    @Override
    public SqlTbUsuariosDao fromString(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}*/

@FXML

private void iniciarsesion(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select Usuario from tbUsuarios where Usuario = '" + txtLogUsuario.getText().trim() + "' And Contraseña ='" + pwdLogUsuario.getText().trim() + "' ");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("UsuarioLogueaod");
            Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPaneLog.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/vistas/MenuPpal.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } else {
            System.out.println("errordesesion");
            Alert error = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE, "Usuario o Contarseña Invalido", ButtonType.OK);
            error.setTitle("Error de Logueo");
            error.showAndWait();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@FXML
private void olvidarcontraseña(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void salirapp(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

**Este es la Clase Usuarios**

```
package ar.com.consular.clases;


import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.property.FloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;



public class TbUsuarios{
private IntegerProperty ID;
private StringProperty Nombre;
private StringProperty Apellido;
private StringProperty Usuario;
private StringProperty Contrasenia;
private IntegerProperty Nivel;
private StringProperty Mail;

public TbUsuarios(int ID, String Nombre, String Apellido, 
String Usuario, String Contrasenia, int Nivel, 
String Mail) { 
    this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
    this.Nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(Nombre);
    this.Apellido = new SimpleStringProperty(Apellido);
    this.Usuario = new SimpleStringProperty(Usuario);
    this.Contrasenia = new SimpleStringProperty(Contrasenia);
    this.Nivel = new SimpleIntegerProperty(Nivel);
    this.Mail = new SimpleStringProperty(Mail);
}

public TbUsuarios(String nombre, String apellido, String usuario, String contrasenia, int nivel, String mail) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

//Metodos atributo: ID
public int getID() {
    return ID.get();
}
public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
}
public IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
    return ID;
}
//Metodos atributo: Nombre
public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre.get();
}
public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
    this.Nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(Nombre);
}
public StringProperty NombreProperty() {
    return Nombre;
}
//Metodos atributo: Apellido
public String getApellido() {
    return Apellido.get();
}
public void setApellido(String Apellido) {
    this.Apellido = new SimpleStringProperty(Apellido);
}
public StringProperty ApellidoProperty() {
    return Apellido;
}
//Metodos atributo: Usuario
public String getUsuario() {
    return Usuario.get();
}
public void setUsuario(String Usuario) {
    this.Usuario = new SimpleStringProperty(Usuario);
}
public StringProperty UsuarioProperty() {
    return Usuario;
}
//Metodos atributo: Contrasenia
public String getContrasenia() {
    return Contrasenia.get();
}
public void setContrasenia(String Contrasenia) {
    this.Contrasenia = new SimpleStringProperty(Contrasenia);
}
public StringProperty ContraseniaProperty() {
    return Contrasenia;
}
//Metodos atributo: Nivel
public int getNivel() {
    return Nivel.get();
}
public void setNivel(int Nivel) {
    this.Nivel = new SimpleIntegerProperty(Nivel);
}
public IntegerProperty NivelProperty() {
    return Nivel;
}
//Metodos atributo: Mail
public String getMail() {
    return Mail.get();
}
public void setMail(String Mail) {
    this.Mail = new SimpleStringProperty(Mail);
}
public StringProperty MailProperty() {
    return Mail;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TbUsuarios{" + "ID=" + ID + ", Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Apellido=" + Apellido + ", Usuario=" + Usuario + ", Contrasenia=" + Contrasenia + ", Nivel=" + Nivel + ", Mail=" + Mail + '}';
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.ID);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Nombre);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Apellido);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Usuario);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Contrasenia);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Nivel);
    hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Mail);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final TbUsuarios other = (TbUsuarios) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.ID, other.ID)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Nombre, other.Nombre)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Apellido, other.Apellido)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Usuario, other.Usuario)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Contrasenia, other.Contrasenia)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Nivel, other.Nivel)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Mail, other.Mail)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

**Este es el Codigo de DAO y debajo el USUARIO DAO (creo que aca le estoy pifiando**

```
public class SqlTbUsuariosDao implements UsuariosDAO {

final String INSERT = "INSERT into TbUsuarios(ID,Nombre,Apellido,Usuario,Contraseña,Nivel,Mail) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
final String UPDATE = "UPDATE TbUsuarios SET Nombre = ?, Apellido = ?, Usuario = ?, Contraseña = ?, Nivel = ?, Mail = ? WHERE ID = ?";
final String DELETE = "DELETE FROM TbUsuarios WHERE ID = ?";
final String GETONE = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Usuario, Contraseña, Nivel, Mail from TbUsuarios";
final String GETALL = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido, Usuario, Contraseña, Nivel, Mail from TbUsuarios WHERE ID=?";

private Connection con;

@Override
public void insetar(TbUsuarios a) throws DAOException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT);
        ps.setInt(1, a.getID());
        ps.setString(2, a.getNombre());
        ps.setString(3, a.getApellido());
        ps.setString(4, a.getUsuario());
        ps.setString(5, a.getContrasenia());
        ps.setInt(6, a.getNivel());
        ps.setString(7, a.getMail());

        if (ps.executeUpdate() == 0) {
            throw new DAOException("Puede que no se haya guardado su Consulta");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void modificar(TbUsuarios a) throws DAOException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE);
        ps.setString(1, a.getNombre());
        ps.setString(2, a.getApellido());
        ps.setString(3, a.getUsuario());
        ps.setString(4, a.getContrasenia());
        ps.setInt(5, a.getNivel());
        ps.setString(6, a.getMail());

        if (ps.executeUpdate() == 0) {
            throw new DAOException("Puede que no se haya Modificado su Consulta");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void eliminar(TbUsuarios a) throws DAOException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(DELETE);
        ps.setInt(1, a.getID());

        if (ps.executeUpdate() == 0) {
            throw new DAOException("Puede que no se haya Borrado su Consulta");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);

    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private TbUsuarios convertir(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    String nombre = rs.getString("Nombre");
    String apellido = rs.getString("Nombre");
    String usuario = rs.getString("Usuario");
    String contrasenia = rs.getString("Contraseña");
    int nivel = rs.getInt("Nivel");
    String mail = rs.getString("Mail");
    TbUsuarios user = new TbUsuarios(nombre, apellido, usuario, contrasenia, nivel, mail);
    user.setID(rs.getInt("ID"));
    return user;
}

@Override
public TbUsuarios obtener(IntegerProperty id) throws DAOException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    TbUsuarios user = null;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(GETONE);
        ps.setInt(1, 0);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            user = convertir(rs);
        } else {
            throw new DAOException("No se encuentra el Usuario");

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);

    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}

@Override
public List<TbUsuarios> obtenerTodos() throws DAOException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<TbUsuarios> user = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(GETALL);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            user.add(convertir(rs));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                new DAOException("Error en SQL", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

**PATRON DAO**
    package ar.com.consular.DAO;

```
import java.util.List;


 public interface DAO<T, K>   {

void insetar(T a) throws DAOException;

void modificar(T a)throws DAOException;

void eliminar(T a)throws DAOException;

List<T> obtenerTodos()throws DAOException;

T obtener(K id)throws DAOException;
}
```

**PATRON USUARIODAO**

```
 public interface UsuariosDAO extends DAO<TbUsuarios, IntegerProperty>{


  }
```

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene dos partes, primera traer los datos de la BD y segunda rellenar el combo-box javafx, si puedes plantear dos preguntas diferentes, puedes dividir el sistema (al menos) en dos partes y solucionar cada parte independientemente.

Answer (score 0):

Como crear combo boxes en JavaFx programáticamente:

```
package combosjavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author orici
 */
public class CombosJavaFx extends Application {

    private static ComboBox<String> numbers;
    private static ComboBox<String> seasons;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));

        Label lbl = new Label("ComboBoxes:");
        createCombos();

        grid.add(lbl, 0, 2);
        grid.add(numbers, 1, 3);
        grid.add(seasons, 2, 5);


        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    private static void createCombos() {
        String[] arr_numbers = {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
        };
        String[] arr_seasons = {
            "winter",
            "spring",
            "summer",
            "autum",
        };


        ObservableList<String> obs_numbers = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr_numbers);
        ObservableList<String> obs_seasons = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr_seasons);

        numbers = new ComboBox(obs_numbers);
        seasons = new ComboBox(obs_seasons);
        seasons.setValue("summer");

        numbers.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String selected) {
                System.out.println("Seleccionado: " + selected);
            }    
        });
        seasons.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String selected) {
                System.out.println("Seleccionado: " + selected);
            }    
        });
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo *JavaFx 8* he añadido a la ventana una etiqueta y dos elementos ComboBox creados a partir de dos arrays de tipo String. Así mismo he añadido *listeners* a los combos para poder imprimir en consola cada opción seleccionada.

Comment: El observable List esta biem de hecho creo que incluso agregando items a la lista la misma los devuelve el Combo.
Yo creo que el problema esta apuntado a como llamo (que seguramente sea ignorante en este tema) sobre la implementación del **DAO** y del intento de llamar al método **OBTENERTODOS**

Comment: No veo donde tienes el error, tendras que ir probando por partes, de momento prueba a imprimir las sentencias SQL y ejecutarlas directamente con un gestor, como phpMyAdmin para ver que esten correctas. Puedes imprimirlas con: `System.out.println(preparedStatement);`